# Weaker condition than uniform convergence to interchange limit and integral

Tags: sequence-of-function

We know that the relation between uniform convergence and integration in case of interchangeability. I.e. Suppose    and    are integrable and fn--->f uniformly on  [,] . Then

lim→∞(a to b)∫fn(x)dx=(a to b)∫f(x)dx. But I want some weaker condition than uniform convergency.  I have seen it a question as follows.  If fn are sequence of non- negative continuous function on [a,b]. which of the following conditions are sufficient for interchangeability of limit and integral as above. 1) fn(x) monotonically increases to f(x) for all x in [a,b]. 2) fn(x)<=f(x) for all x in [a,b]. 3) f is continuous. I think the first two option are like Monotone convergence theorem an Dominated convergence theorem in Measure Theory, but I can not simplify it to Reimann Integration case. Please someone help me to do.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Any Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ is also Lebesgue integrable. So you are free to use MCT and DCT.